# What can we expect from god?

Tags: gods, karma, vedic-gods

Can we expect help from god? What exactly can we expect because I see some people praying but not all their prayers are getting fulfilled therefore I conclude god doesn't work like that, I see people dying of hunger praying for food but they dont get any food therefore I conclude god doesnt work like that, how exactly does god work and why should I believe you? And when can we expect help from god?

Answer (score 1):

In the dualistic interpretation of Hinduism, *god* or *Ishvara* is regarded as an entity who is regarded as the basis of the whole existence of everything, who is the source of all true knowledge and creator, sustainer, and destroyer of everything in the universe.

Praying (or devotion or *bhakti*) to the Ishvara sheds the light of knowledge to the devotee and gets him the knowledge with whom he becomes liberated from the material world, misery, birth and attains the abode of the Ishvara.

---

In non-dualistic intrepretation of Hinduism, *god* or *brahman* is regarded as own consciousness of the individial. The realization of true self (or God) is what gives him elightment (jivanmukta or knowledge of liberation), with whom he gets liberated from laws of karma and physicality and attains *Nirvana*.

In this intrepretation, laws of karma are self evident and no additional *ishvara* is required to enforce them.

---

> What exactly can we expect because I see some people praying but not
> all their prayers are getting fulfilled therefore I conclude god
> doesn't work like that, I see people dying of hunger praying for food
> but they dont get any food therefore I conclude god doesnt work like
> that, how exactly does god work and why should I believe you?

*Ishvara* is one who is supposed to liberate you from all your miseries.  He's supposed to take you beyond all the hunger, death, and misery. He's the most powerful being who can shed light of knowledge so that one can become free from all misery. *Life or death*, *hunger or fullness*, *warm or cold*, etc like dualities are all attributes of *maya*. *Maya* is an illusion that takes you away from Ishvara. Those who pray and are steadfast in devotion to the Ishvara, get free from all Maya.

---

Meanwhile, there are *celestial gods* or *demigods* who can manifest wishes and are very fast in manifestation of their devotees. They are themselves part of the Maya, but despite their immediate response to their devotees with the required manifestations, they don't remove miseries. Miseries are consequences of *ignorance* and we pray to god (or Ishvara) to move ourselves away from ignorance and take us towards knowledge, hence liberate us from all suffering all at once at their abode.